# ASP.NET MVC + Web API running along: get routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution that contains an ASP.NET Core Web API along with an ASP.NET Core MVC application.

I intend to use the API in the MVC application, and they are both running at the same time.

For instance, the API is running on `localhost:60170` and I have a controller routed to `"api/[controller]"` as follows:

```
namespace JobManager.WAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
```

Now, how do I get the routes in my MVC application to the API, without hardcoding the path to the API, i.e. `localhost:60170` ?

Comment: You could use [Hyprlinkr](https://github.com/ploeh/Hyprlinkr).

Comment: There is no such thing as ASP.NET Core Web Api. MVC and Web Api have merged in Core.

Comment: @NightOwl888: Don't think that will work here. The problem seems to be that the user has created two separate projects, and now wants to share routes between them.

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes that's it!

Comment: @manatttta: You can't share routes between projects. If your website and api are hosted as separate applications, then hardcoding the API paths is unavoidable. You can mitigate some of the damage by using something like Application Settings to store the URLs for the endpoints you need, as then you'd only have to hardcode it in one place, but it will have to be hardcoded.

Comment: Rather than actually storing every endpoint in App Settings, though, it would probably be better to employ something like Refit (https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit). This library lets you model APIs via interfaces, which you can then call in strongly-typed ways. All you would need to keep in App Settings is the base URI, which you could then switch out based on environment using config transforms.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller can have both the API methods and MVC methods 'hand-in-hand'.

You can first define your default MVC route in `Startup.cs`:

```
        // mvc
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

in the controller class, remove the controller attribute `[Route("api/[controller]")]`, instead, use it to decorate the specific API method inside the controller class, for example:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/XYZ/{..}")]

public IActionResult ABC(..){

}
```

For MVC methods, just use them as normal:

```
[HttpGet]

public async Task<IActionResult> Index(..){

}
```

Don't hard code the `localhost` address.

Comment: I don't think I understood. How can it access the API methods without me referring to the API port, at least?

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood the intent. my solution allows you to have one project to handle both API service and MVC web front end part.